# Htaccess ErrorDocument 404 don't work with php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My htaccess:

```
# Indique que la page erreur est de type 404
ErrorDocument 404 /Erreur.php?E=2
```

https://feoval.fr/indexz -> well redirected

https://feoval.fr/indexz.php -> return "File not found."

How i can catch the .php file ?

Comment: Could you post what you've done in your .htaccess?

Comment: My htaccess have only what i have write upper

Comment: So you want people to be redirected to your Error page upon visiting indexz.php?

Comment: yes like all pages that do not exist

Comment: try to set `/Erreur.php` with a full path

Comment: Nop it's the same with full path